# Primefaces Chart Tick Interval

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jqplot

Hi I need x axes labels only at particular intervals in the primefaces horizontal bar chart.

script extender:

```
<script>
            function skinBar() {
                this.cfg.shadow = false;
                this.cfg.title = '';
                this.cfg.seriesColors = [ '#FF9000', '#DE6829', '#9DCC09',
                        '#71BDE9', '#EDCE00' ];
                this.cfg.grid = {
                    background : '#ffffff',
                    borderColor : '#ffffff',
                    gridLineColor : '#F5F5F5',
                    shadow : false,
                    borderWidth : 0
                };
                this.cfg.legend = {
                    show : true,
                    location : 'ne',
                    placement : 'outsideGrid'
                };
                this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.fontSize = '7.5pt';
                this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.tickInterval = '100000';
                this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "%'d";
            };
        </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use an extender, why don't try to change the interval directly in the axis?

```
BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();
...
Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
xAxis.setTickInterval("100000");
```

But if you actually want to do it using some sort of extender, try to do:

```
function skinBar() {
    this.cfg.axes = {
        xaxis : {
            tickOptions : { 
                fontSize:'7.5pt',         
                formatString: '%d',
            },
            tickInterval:'100000'
        },
    };
}
```